# Why are physists using intergrals without specifying limits?

Tags: conventions, notation, integration

Take an integral like this as an example:

$$\int U(\vec{r})e^{i\vec{q}\cdot\vec{r}/\hbar}d^3\vec{r},$$

which has somethng to do with scattering. The integration is over all space so correctly it should be

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} U(\vec{r})e^{i\vec{q}\cdot\vec{r}/\hbar}d^3\vec{r}.$$

Why do we keep seeing thses integrals without this crucial piece of information? It is only obvious if you already are familiar with the particular theory. But ifyou're learning new things you can't know that. Maybe the limits are the interior of a sphere, or a cube, tather than all space?

Is there some kind of a general rule I can apply to determine what we're supposed to integrate over?

Comment: The range of integration is evident from the context of the problem we are doing.

Comment: I don't see how answers to this question can be more that opinions. For what it's worth my opinion is that we are physicists first and mathematicians second. You start by understanding the physical principles, and once you do the limits of integrals will be obvious from the physical interpretation of the integral.